# Starting out with MongoDB - Beginner advice/tools

Tags: mongodb

I new to this forum and new to MongoDB.

I am currently taking the 10gen online education course for MongoDB and have been doing some of the online tutorials.  However, my programming experience is limited to classroom experience mainly in java with some experience in SQL, python.

As I have been going through the tutorials, I have noticed a gap in knowledge in some key areas and a gap in the tools that I should be using for development.  I would like to fill in these gap asap as best as possible.

I am asking for advice on any forums that I should join or look at, websites, software I should be getting (basically any tools that a programmer should have, i am mainly just using eclipse), or just general advice on what you wish you knew when you were starting out..

Thanks!

Comment: Pleas ask more specific questions to those gaps.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is far too open-ended for the Q&A format of stackoverflow.com. You are essentially asking for "Everything a programmer is supposed to know". Please be more specific about which knowledge areas you think you have gaps in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
sudo nano  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list 
Add the line
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen

sudo nano /etc/mongodb.conf 
sudo nano /etc/init.d/mongodb.conf
sudo service mongodb start
mongo
> db.test.save( { a: 1 } )
> db.test.find()


sudo apt-get install php-pear 
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
sudo apt-get install make
wget https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
 or
sudo pecl install mongo

cp /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mongo.so  /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mongo.so
cp /lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

If you are using Windows:

Download 
Mongodb

http://www.mongodb.org/downloads

and 
mongodb-php driver

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads

You may also need RockMongo (similar to phpmyadmin) 
http://rockmongo.com/downloads